# Remove parent element if child does not exist

Tags: jquery

I have several **td's** with a class of **.container**. I want to remove the whole **td.container** if it does not contain the link **a.tickets**. In the example below it would be the second td.

```
<td class="container">
<span>date info</span>
<a href="#" class="tickets">one</a>
</td>
<td class="container">
<span>date info</span>
</td>
```

I was thinking to check if the class exists using this below but that wont work. What do I need to add to ignore the ones that do have the **.ticket** class? Also would .closest remove this or .parent?

```
if($("td.container a.tickets").length < 0)
{
something like .closest('td').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you can use a combination of the `:not()` and `:has()` selectors, like this:

```js
$('td.container:not(:has(.tickets))').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <td class="container">
    <span>date info</span>
    <a href="#" class="tickets">one</a>
  </td>
  <td class="container">
    <span>date info</span>
  </td>
</table>
```

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of jQuery `.filter()` and a simple `querySelector()` :

```js
$('td.container').filter((_, e) => !e.querySelector('a.tickets')).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="container">
      <span>date info</span>
      <a href="#" class="tickets">one</a>
    </td>
    <td class="container">
      <span>date info</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

EDIT: Since *@Rory McCrossan* already gave you an easier answer, here is a Javascript only answer, just because :

```
document.querySelectorAll('td.container').forEach(e => {if(!e.querySelector('a.tickets')) e.remove();});
```

Comment: :not and :has is more consistent than mixing querySelectors into it

Comment: @mplungjan In which way?

Comment: You have jQuery, no need to filter and no need to use querySelector which is what is likely used by :has anyway.`$('td.container:not(:has(.tickets))').remove();` is in my mind simpler and more elegant use of jQUery

Comment: @mplungjan Oh, you mean it's the same thing but `:has` is more easily readable. I agree. I never think about using it, hence my answer ^^

Comment: Ah, your second version is the ES6 version of my answer :/ But again with the filter???

Comment: @mplungjan I guess I'm obsessed with it ^^'. I'll just replace it with a simple `if` in the `forEach` loop, in this case it's much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Plain JS, just because it is not that harder to do/read than jQuery

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove

```js
document.querySelectorAll('td.container').forEach(function(ele) {
 if (ele.querySelector('a.tickets') == null) ele.remove(); // not jQuery
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="container">
      <span>date info</span>
      <a href="#" class="tickets">one</a>
    </td>
    <td class="container">
      <span>date info</span>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```